# How to reduce vertical spacing between H2 header and html div

Tags: html, github, formatting, readme

I have a section on my github personal repository readme where a list my skill set, but the standard vertical spacing between the text of the section and the div right below is a bit exaggerated...

(see the picture [picture discribing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlF00.png))

Note in the attached picture that I already tried to set margin and padding to 0px but nothing changed.

Comment: Supply code, not just images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spacing seems to be happening because of the spacing on the h2 itself and not the div. Try setting the padding and margin of the h2 to 0 and see if that fixes it.

Additionally, you can **Right Click** on the element where the spacing is occurring and select **Inspect Element**. This will allow you to check what is causing the gap in the "**Computed**" tab of the Styles panel.

Another nifty tip is setting the box-sizing, margin and padding of all elements to 0 from the get go. This way you'll be able to manually control the spacing across all your elements without any unexpected gaps that you need to debug later.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<div>Test Div</div>
```

Comment: thank you, I followed your advice in inspect the html and I found some <br> tags that was adding the over spacing